# KeyError: 'wallets'

Tags: wallets, nft, smart-contract-wallets, brownie

Screenshot of directory:

[image: Directory]

This is the code in my brownie.config.yaml file:

```
reports:
  exclude_contracts:
    - SafeMath
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
 wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
  from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
```

Code from deploy_advanced.py:

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config

def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(dev)
```

When I try to run 'brownie run scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py' I get the following error:

```
Running 'scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py", line 4, in main
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
KeyError: 'wallets'
```

Any advice on how to fix this error?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your config, as in, brownie isn't picking up your config file. Could you add a picture of what your directory looks like?

Comment: Just updated it with my directory. I did happen to notice that my config file is called brownie.config.yaml vs brownie-config.yaml, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: It does. How did you get brownie.config.yaml?

Comment: Great question that I wish I had the answer too , I was wondering the same thing, must've been a typo on my end... It's now correctly pointing at the config, but i'm getting a "ParserError: while parsing a block mapping" message, is that due to a syntax error?

Comment: Sounds like a new question ;)

Comment: Done lol  Link: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98444/parsererror-while-parsing-a-block-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed brownie.config.yaml -> brownie-config.yaml